# Duplicate substitution definition name with only::

Tags: css, python-sphinx, substitution, pdflatex

I'm using Sphinx to build our end user manuals, consisting of many long tables. Special table cells should be highlighted with a color. I derived a solution working for HTML and likewise for LaTeX.

Now I wanted to combine both solution into the rst-files, by using the only directive.

```
.. only:: html

   .. |bS| raw:: html

              <div style="color:blue;">
       
   .. |bE| raw:: html
       
              </div>

.. only:: latex

   .. |bS| raw:: latex

              \cellcolor{blue} 
       
   .. |bE| raw:: latex
       
              \empty{}
```

Sphinx-build now issues the errors:

```
WARNING: Duplicate substitution definition name: "bS".
WARNING: Duplicate substitution definition name: "bE".
```

And I have `\cellcolor{blue}` in my HTML Output, which isn't supposed to happen.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What are your commands that you use to build the docs? Perhaps an alternative would be [`ifconfig`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/ifconfig.html)

Comment: There are problems with the `only` directive. See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2150

Comment: @mzjn: Thanks for this hint. It is possible to switch to ifconfig instead?